# Macro redefinition works on some compilers but not others. What decides this?

Tags: c, macros

I wrote 2 macros and tested the code in an online compiler, but when moved to the CCS PIC 4.032 compiler it gives the "Macro is defined recursivly" error.

```
#define MIN_VALUE_2(a, b)         (((a) < (b)) ? a : b)
#define MIN_VALUE_4(a, b, c, d)   MIN_VALUE_2(MIN_VALUE_2(a, b), MIN_VALUE_2(c, d))
```

Most compilers I tried accept this. So the questions are:

1. Why doesn't the CCS compiler work with this? (technically, the preprocessor)
2. Are there 2 stages necessary to do the replacement? With this being the result of the first stage? Or how does the preprocessor work?

`#define MIN_VALUE_4(a, b, c, d) (((MIN_VALUE_2(a, b)) < (MIN_VALUE_2(c, d))) ? MIN_VALUE_2(a, b) : MIN_VALUE_2(c, d))`

Comment: I don't see a recursive macro definition. I would take this up with the compiler vendor.

Comment: Using a macro name in its own definition is not an error in C, si a compiler which complains about it is definitely suspect. But none of those definitions are recursive. Which one does the compiler complain about?

Comment: Also: in what sense do you think this is"macro redefinition"(which is an error)? Are you using all three of those definitions?

Comment: Possibly unrelated: I'd add more parenthesis around a and b in `#define MIN_VALUE_2(a, b)         (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))`

Comment: Try: remove spaces between `a, b, c, d` and `a, b`. Actually, remove _all_  spaces

Comment: Probably just another day in the wonderful world of smelly embedded systems compilers.

Comment: Since there are no temporary variables the arguments could be evaluated up to 4 times each.

Comment: The first question is a bit odd. I'm not sure what answer you expect. Anyway, whether it is allowed by the C standard or not, whether this compiler is right or wrong to output an error,  I don't think  the definition of `MIN_VALUE_4` is very clean. Wouldn't it be better to define an inline function or write the macro differently ? The current implementation is error prone. Use macros with care.

Comment: @rici, The compiler complains not at the #define, but at the first use of it. Sorry, I should have mentioned that.
"Macro redefinition" is probably incorrect from my side. I'm only using the first 2. The third was an example of me trying to understand how the preprocessor works through the second macro. And was wondering if it needs 2 passes to expand it correctly, and maybe this wasn't implemented in the CCS compiler.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Unfortunately that wasn't it.

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean I was thinking that maybe in an old C standard this wasn't allowed, or something along these lines. Or maybe someone ran into this problem and knows why this particular compiler doesn't behave and how to fix it.

Comment: @dragos: you still haven't mentioned *which* macro the error applies to. I suppose it is `MIN_VALUE_4`.

Comment: @rici, Sorry, yes. When I try to use the MIN_VALUE_4 macro.

Comment: Some compilers have an option to output the source after the preprocessor processed it. Does your compiler have such, and if yes, did you try it?

Comment: @thebusybee Thanks for the tip, but unfortunately from what I can gather on the CCS forums, this functionality doesn't exist. Regardless, I'll work around it.

Comment: The standard is quite clear about the expected working of the preprocessor. You might like to use in example GCC's preprocessor to see what a conformant beast does. If CCS' preprocessor does not conform, consider to use another one.